# jQuery reset remove padding on header based on screen size

Tags: jquery

Why is my `jQuery` not resetting when I resize my screen. It seems to keep the padding-top on the body even though I am scaling it to be larger than the 768px.

I am attaching the `js` hoping it is enough. If you need the `HTML` as well as the `CSS` I will set up a fiddle to help.

```
(function ($) {
  $(function () {
    var headerHeight = $('.stickyHeader').innerHeight();

    $( window ).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        if ($('.stickyHeader')[0]){
        // do something for small screens
        $('body').css(
          {
            'padding-top': headerHeight + 'px'
          }
        );

        $(window).bind('resize', function() {
          $('body').css(
            {
              'padding-top': headerHeight + 'px'
            }
          );
        });
        $( "body" ).offset({ top: 0, left: 0 });
      }
}


      else if ($(window).width() >= 768 &&  $(window).width() <= 992) {
        // do something for medium screens
      }
      else if ($(window).width() > 992 &&  $(window).width() <= 1200) {
        // do something for big screens
      }
      else  {
        // do something for huge screens
      }
    });
  });
})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: `jQuery.bind()` is deprecated in 3.0. You should use `.on()`. Have you checked if the event fires at all? Is there a reason you can't use CSS media queries?

Comment: Can you put jsfiddle here?

Comment: I will work on a codepen here tonight. I need to get a few things done. A few issues i have found with my answer is that it only fires the jQuery on resize. I need to somehow combine the resize with the page load so if the page loads in a mobile device it adds the padding to the body right away and doesn't require resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i took a few more minutes and tried exploring additional things for the other screen sizes. This seems to work for what i need it to do. I hope it can help others in a similar situation.

```
(function ($) {
  $(function () {
    var headerHeight = $('.stickyHeader').innerHeight();

    $( window ).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        if ($('.stickyHeader')[0]){
        // do something for small screens
        $('body').css(
          {
            'padding-top': headerHeight + 'px'
          }
        );

        $(window).bind('width', function() {
          $('body').css(
            {
              'padding-top': headerHeight + 'px'
            }
          );
        });
        $( "body" ).offset({ top: 0, left: 0 });
      }

}


      else if ($(window).width() >= 768 &&  $(window).width() <= 992) {
        // do something for medium screens
        $('body').css(
          {
            'padding-top': 0
          }
        );
      }
      else if ($(window).width() > 992 &&  $(window).width() <= 1200) {
        // do something for big screens
      }
      else  {
        // do something for huge screens
      }
    });
  });
})(window.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery for that.
css media query is enough for you.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .header{
   padding:0;
 }
}
```

Comment: The header is content managed and will not be the same size all the time. I need the jQuery to find its height. The issue was when i resized the browser to be mobile it worked but when i made it larger again it never fired the javascript to get the innerHeight.